# Google Analytics "Behavior Flow" to and from a given Page

Tags: google-analytics

I want to use "Behavior Flow" (or "Users Flow" or "Visitors Flow" – I'm not sure how the most recent term is as I'm using german Analytics site) in Google Analytics to find out how many users that started their visit on the root page (`/`) click through to the Press page (`/press.html`). So I choose dimension "Landing Page" and restrict it to "equals /". Now I have five pages below "1st interaction", but `press.html` is none of them as it's hidden within "+100 more pages". I tried to define a segment with users that visited `press.html` in their session, but this kind of segment can't be used on Users Flow.

If their would be a way to list more than five individual pages below "1st interaction", "2nd interaction" etc. this would solve my problem. Even better would be to just show a chosen page on a single step ("1st interaction", "2nd interaction" and so on).

This is some kind of ad-hoc analysis with the data that's available in Analytics by default. So defining goals or similar methods that are not available instantaneously doesn't help me in this case. And this case happens rather often as my clients often don't know what they want to know in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are specifically interested in landing pages to second pages, there is a nice report hidden in the Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages report that is easier to work with than any of the Flow reports.

From Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages switch the report tab from Explorer to Entrance Paths.

[image: Screenshot of top of Landing Pages report with tab switched to Entrance Paths]

You'll have a drop-down from which you can select `/` as the landing page, and a table underneath of second pages - but with a filtration/search box underneath, so you can restrict to `press.html`.

[image: Screenshot of Landing Pages report, Entrance Paths tab]

However, I believe you can also get what you want from Behavior Flow; it's just more work to get to it. Having changed the View Type to Automatically Grouped Pages, you can click on `/` as the Landing Page to view only that segment, and then click on the "(100 more pages)" heading to bring up a Group Details table that will list out those hundred pages.

[image: Screenshot of filtering Behavior Flow report to a single Landing Page]

[image: Screenshot of a Group Details popup]

If you are lucky enough to be considering one of the pages that is listed individually, you can click on it to explore traffic through that page, with your landing page restriction still in effect. I found it a little flaky - the page just froze the first time I tried it - but once I got through it was an informative report for its limited use case. Unfortunately that does not appear to be available for the lower-traffic pages, though.